# pyomo + reticulate error 6 the handle is invalid

Tags: python, r, pyomo, reticulate

I'm trying to run a `pyomo` optimization and I get the error message `[Error 6] The handle is invalid`. Not sure how to interpret it, looking around it seems to have something to do with privileges but I don't really understand it.

Find below the complete error trace and also a toy example to reproduce it.

Full error trace:

> Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) :    ApplicationError:
>   Could not execute the command:
>   'C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\lucy\Library\bin\ipopt.exe
>   c:\users\xxx\appdata\local\temp\tmpp2hmid.pyomo.nl -AMPL'     Error
>   message: [Error 6] The handle is invalid
>
> Detailed traceback:    File "", line 46, in    File
>   "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\lucy\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\base\solvers.py",
>   line 578, in solve
>       _status = self._apply_solver()   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\lucy\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py",
>   line 246, in _apply_solver
>       self._rc, self._log = self._execute_command(self._command)   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\lucy\lib\site-packages\pyomo\opt\solver\shellcmd.py",
>   line 309, in _execute_command
>       tee   = self._tee   File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\CONTIN~1\ANACON~1\envs\lucy\lib\site-packages\pyutilib\subprocess\processmngr.py",
>   line 660, in run_command

Reproducible example based on [this](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Pyomo/PyomoGallery/blob/master/diet/DietProblem.ipynb).

Pure python code (it works when I run it in python, in the `conda` environment called "lucy"):

```
from pyomo.environ import *
infinity = float('inf')

model = AbstractModel()

# Foods
model.F = Set()
# Nutrients
model.N = Set()

# Cost of each food
model.c    = Param(model.F, within=PositiveReals)
# Amount of nutrient in each food
model.a    = Param(model.F, model.N, within=NonNegativeReals)
# Lower and upper bound on each nutrient
model.Nmin = Param(model.N, within=NonNegativeReals, default=0.0)
model.Nmax = Param(model.N, within=NonNegativeReals, default=infinity)
# Volume per serving of food
model.V    = Param(model.F, within=PositiveReals)
# Maximum volume of food consumed
model.Vmax = Param(within=PositiveReals)

# Number of servings consumed of each food
model.x = Var(model.F, within=NonNegativeIntegers)

# Minimize the cost of food that is consumed
def cost_rule(model):
    return sum(model.c[i]*model.x[i] for i in model.F)
model.cost = Objective(rule=cost_rule)

# Limit nutrient consumption for each nutrient
def nutrient_rule(model, j):
    value = sum(model.a[i,j]*model.x[i] for i in model.F)
    return model.Nmin[j] <= value <= model.Nmax[j]
model.nutrient_limit = Constraint(model.N, rule=nutrient_rule)

# Limit the volume of food consumed
def volume_rule(model):
    return sum(model.V[i]*model.x[i] for i in model.F) <= model.Vmax
model.volume = Constraint(rule=volume_rule)

opt = SolverFactory('ipopt')
instance = model.create_instance('diet.dat')
results = opt.solve(instance, tee=False)
results
```

The code to run it in R with `reticulate` is pretty straightforward:

```
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv(condaenv = "lucy")
py_run_file("../pyomo_scripts/test.py")
```

And finally for completeness this is the `diet.dat` file (must be at the same path as the python/R files):

```
param:  F:                          c     V  :=
  "Cheeseburger"                 1.84   4.0  
  "Ham Sandwich"                 2.19   7.5  
  "Hamburger"                    1.84   3.5  
  "Fish Sandwich"                1.44   5.0  
  "Chicken Sandwich"             2.29   7.3  
  "Fries"                         .77   2.6  
  "Sausage Biscuit"              1.29   4.1  
  "Lowfat Milk"                   .60   8.0 
  "Orange Juice"                  .72  12.0 ;

param Vmax := 75.0;

param:  N:       Nmin   Nmax :=
        Cal      2000      .
        Carbo     350    375
        Protein    55      .
        VitA      100      .
        VitC      100      .
        Calc      100      .
        Iron      100      . ;

param a:
                               Cal  Carbo Protein   VitA   VitC  Calc  Iron :=
  "Cheeseburger"               510     34     28     15      6    30    20
  "Ham Sandwich"               370     35     24     15     10    20    20
  "Hamburger"                  500     42     25      6      2    25    20
  "Fish Sandwich"              370     38     14      2      0    15    10
  "Chicken Sandwich"           400     42     31      8     15    15     8
  "Fries"                      220     26      3      0     15     0     2
  "Sausage Biscuit"            345     27     15      4      0    20    15
  "Lowfat Milk"                110     12      9     10      4    30     0
  "Orange Juice"                80     20      1      2    120     2     2 ;
```

---

*edit after comments*:

These are the versions for `pyomo` and `ipopt`

```
pyomo                     5.6.4                    py36_0    conda-forge
pyomo.extras              3.3                 py36_182212    conda-forge
ipopt                     3.11.1                        2    conda-forge
```

I have inherited loads of code in R with the optimization done in `pyomo` through system calls. I'm trying to improve it by using `reticulate` so that I avoid writing and reading files and I have more control... if I still have do system calls within python, I will gain very little by using `reticulate`.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Pyomo are you using? How are you using Pyomo to solve the model, using the `pyomo` command line interface or using a Python script?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can execute the python version, try to r session with administrative right with the following code

```
library("reticulate")


##-- your directory containing 'diet.py' and 'diet.dat'
setwd("D:/project/Dropbox/lectures/2104xxx scg_opt/src/02"")



##-- execute code
a <- py_run_file("diet.py",local=T)
a$results
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to be working! The key is the `setwd` so that the file `diet.dat` may be read. Administrator rights don't seem to be needed. Again thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I can not say I understand this problem entirely, however it is a very interesting one to research, mainly because I got a different error message

> TypeError: signal handler must be signal.SIG_IGN, signal.SIG_DFL, or a callable object

and while I got the error every time I ran `py_run_file("test.py")` in a new r session, by the second run there was no error.

That being said I believe it is related to this issue:
https://github.com/PyUtilib/pyutilib/issues/31

I didn't face any problem after adding the two lines :

```
import pyutilib.subprocess.GlobalData
pyutilib.subprocess.GlobalData.DEFINE_SIGNAL_HANDLERS_DEFAULT = False
```

in the python script before invoking the solver.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. However I did a quick test and I get the same error message... I'll take a slower look at the issue you link and I'll let you know.

Comment: Although this answer does not really work for me, the bounty goes automatically since it is the only one.. And anyway it was helpful, thank you for that. However, since the error message is not really the same, I'd appreciate details on your machine and software versions, so that I can maybe get a hint on how to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: Sure! The pyomo and ipopt were the same as yours, system wise I was on a MacOS Mojave, with the preview version of Rstudio v1.2 and reticulate 1.10

Comment: As I don't have access to that machine anymore I will be trying again on a windows 10 and I'l get back to you on that